# golang json 'true' is no True?

Tags: go

I am just learning golang， json to struct,Get boolean value is always false,
if my json "remember":true, get boolean value is true,how to solve?
my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type AdminInfoRequest struct {
    Id          uint   `json:"id"`
    UserName    string `json:"username"`
    Password    string `json:"password"`
    CaptchaId   string `json:"captcha_id"`
    Captcha     string `json:"captcha"`
    Remember    bool   `json:"remember"`
    Status      uint   `json:"status"`
    GroupId     uint   `json:"group_id"`
    OldPassword string `json:"old_password"`
    RePassword  string `json:"re_password"`
}

func main() {
    var s AdminInfoRequest
    j := `{"username":"admin","remember":"true"}`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &s)
    fmt.Println(s.UserName)
    fmt.Println(s.Remember)
}
```

Comment: `"true"` != `true`. Note that `json.Unmarshal` returns an error value that explains the issue. You should never ignore errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON, `"true"` is a string value. Try this:

```
j := `{"username":"admin","remember":true}`
```

Comment: i get data true is a string . if string how to solve?

Comment: @xin.chen https://go.dev/play/p/l047qOZ1Zur (custom bool type which implements the `json.Unmarshaler` interface)